# I want to apply loop but i don't know how to apply it on my code

Tags: python, loops

here's my code

```
#Program for calculating the nTH Term
sequence=range(0,40,3)
a=int(input("The first term is:"))
d=int(input("The common difference is:"))
n=len(sequence)
print("The number of terms is:",n)
print("The last term of sequence is: ")
Tn=a+((n-1)*d)
print(Tn)
```

how can i make this code to run again using if condition and with new values which i will input again ORrr i just have to put an if condition and copy/paste my code inside it?

Comment: inside a while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    sequence=range(0,40,3)
    a=int(input("The first term is:"))
    d=int(input("The common difference is:"))
    n=len(sequence)
    print("The number of terms is:",n)
    print("The last term of sequence is: ")
    Tn=a+((n-1)*d)
    print(Tn)
```

This will loop forever, so you need to decide on a end condition and replace `while True` with something that can become false at some point

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
def inputs():
    a=int(input("The first term is:"))
    d=int(input("The common difference is:"))
    return (a, d)

def nth_term():
    a, d = inputs()
    sequence=range(0,40,3)
    n=len(sequence)
    print()
    print("The number of terms is:",n)
    print("The last term of sequence is: ")
    Tn=a+((n-1)*d)
    print(Tn)
```

Then each time you want it to be called you can just call `nth_term()`.  If you wanted to call it a certain number of times you could put it in a loop like this:

```
for each in range(5):
    nth_term()
```